Bringing binary data into React component via import statement
I'd like to set up a React hook (or functional component) to read data in from gzip-compressed file, using the pako library to extract its data, and then render it in the browser.
Edit: The compressed binary file is local to the project. It is not hosted on a web server elsewhere.
A simple test I had in mind looked similar to this:
import { memo } from 'react';

import compressedFile from "./data.json.gz";

import './App.css';

const pako = require('pako');

const App = memo(({}) => {

  try {
    const compressedBytes = new Uint8Array(compressedFile);
    const uncompressedStr = pako.inflate(compressedBytes, { to: 'string' });

    return (
      <div>
        Data: <pre>{uncompressedStr}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return (
      <div>
        Error: <pre>{err}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default App

However, this did not work due to the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at data.json.gz?import:1:1)

The file data.json.gz is in the same directory as App and is just a gzip-compressed test file, e.g.:
$ echo -e '{"a":123,"b":456}' | gzip -c > data.json.gz

Can import be used to read in binary data? Is there another way to read in a binary file either directly or indirectly into a byte array I can process with pako?
Please note that I am looking for an answer specifically about working directly with a binary file, and not a base-64 or other re-encoded file that is a string.

I believe you would need to fetch it and use FileReader.

I am not hosting this binary file on a web server elsewhere; it is contained within the project. Does fetch work in accessing a file local to the project? It looks like it makes HTTP requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

@AlexReynolds yes, it does, just've tested it before posting an answer :)

As far as I know, the module system expects a file structure that can be parsed into a format that JavaScript can understand and execute. Binary files do not fall into that category by default.
I can think of two ways to deal with this issue:
Configuring file-loader from Webpack.
Or simply by using fetch:
const response = await fetch("/data.json.gz");
const compressedBytes = await response.arrayBuffer();


fyi, react made me to put file into /public directory by default to use this particular relative path

You can use untar-js and pako to extract and read a tarball in the browser.
Here is an example with the Maven binary:
Note: See the extractFiles function near the bottom.


const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;

const TarballExplorer = ({ path }) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    extractFiles(path).then((extractedFiles) => {
      setFiles(sortByFilePaths(extractedFiles.map(mapFile)));
    });
  }, [path]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Viewing files in {path.split('/').pop()}</h1>
      <ul>
        {files.map(file => (
          <li key={file.name}>{file.name} ({filesize(file.size)})</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(
    <StrictMode>
      <TarballExplorer
        path="https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.9-bin.tar.gz"
      />
    </StrictMode>
);

// Simplify a file object to store in state
function mapFile(file) {
  const { name, size } = file;
  return { name, size };
}

// Fetch a tarball, decompress it, and return the file names and sizes
function extractFiles(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetch(path)
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(buffer => {
        // Decompress the tarball using pako (output is a Uint8Array)
        const decompressedData = pako.ungzip(buffer);

        // Use js-untar from the window object to unpack the ArrayBuffer
        untar(decompressedData.buffer).then((extractedFiles) => {
          resolve(extractedFiles)
        });
      });
  })
}

// Sort files by their names (aka paths)
function sortByFilePaths(files) {
  return files.sort((a, b) => {
    const aParts = a.name.split('/');
    const bParts = b.name.split('/');

    // Compare directories or files until there's a difference
    for (let i = 0, len = Math.min(aParts.length, bParts.length); i < len; i++) {
      const comparison = aParts[i].localeCompare(bParts[i]);
      if (comparison !== 0) return comparison;
    }

    // If all directories match, prioritize directories over files
    return Math.sign(bParts.length - aParts.length);
  });
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/filesize/9.0.11/filesize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pako@2.1.0/dist/pako.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/InvokIT/js-untar@2.0.0/build/dist/untar.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



